# Good resource for p-thinning of a point process

Tags: probability, distributions, stochastic-processes, distance-functions, point-process

Can you please tell me what is a good resource about p-thinning of a point process and then finding the distance between the original and obtained process? Something like the Kullback Leibler distance, variation distance , etc?